# Mac app: remove trial version when installing licensed App Store version

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mac-app-store

I've developed a Mac app which I'm going to distribute through the Mac App Store.
I've also made a trial version which I want to distribute through my website. When the trial period has passed, the user is presented a link to the App Store so she can buy the actual licensed app.

What I'd like to know is; what is the best way to make sure that when the App Store version is being installed, the trial version is overwritten? What if the trial version is still running? Should I make sure it is killed? Can the App Store install an app if there already exists one with the same name in the Applications directory? I don't want the user to have 2 apps installed with the same name. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make them ONE app .. same bundle identifier.

One app cannot delete another app

but the appstore can OVERWRITE an existing app IIRC